# Background image too large in window/view

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

I am playing around with a very small single view application in order to understand how views work.  I am extremely new to iOS development.  I am using an image i put together as a background for my only view.  When running the app my background is enormous.  It's as if it is zoomed in or scaled.  I am following a Big Nerd Ranch tutorial for views and as such I'm using a subclass of UIView called HypnosisView.  This is temporary.  It may also we worth noting that the image I am trying to use for a background is precisely 640 x 1136 pixels.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 1136);

    HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]]];
    [[self window] addSubview:view];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Updated code trying to implement a UIImageView using a 0, 0, 320, 568 frame. I also created a 320 sized background and then a full sized background and named them with the proper titles.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);


    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background@2x.png"];
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

    [[self window] addSubview:backgroundView];
    [[self window] sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So the image you have is 640 by 1136 but you say that when it displays in your UIView, the image is actually larger than 640 by 1136?

Comment: It would appear so.  It's like I can only see the top left quarter of the image.

Comment: The maximum viewable area of a UIView in iPhone 5 is only 320 x 568. If your image is larger than that area, you will see only a portion of it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view frame is larger than your screen, your image will be clipped if it too is bigger. You can either use a UIScrollView, shrink the original image down to size or scale your image with code like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);


UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"];

UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[background CGImage]
                                           scale:(background.scale * 2.0)
                                     orientation:(background.imageOrientation)];

UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

[[self window] addSubview:backgroundView];
[[self window] sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

(my scale factor is based on an image size of 640x1136)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you run your app and the image is lager the the window Screen, so you think that the image is actually lager than 640*1136? If i am right about that, i can tell you why. That's because in programing, iphone screen's height is 568 and width is 320, and in your code, you created a 640*1136 view which is twice as big as the window's frame. So at last it presented only part of your image.

Comment: I adjusted my view to be 320*568 and the issue still persists.

Comment: This was it.  I just needed to resize my image.  It doesn't make any sense to me to have an image 50% the required size because I feel that it would multiply the pixels and look terrible but it works perfectly.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @sdfrien if you want it to display just the right pixels, try creating two pics, one is 320*568 and the other is 640*1136. And name them like xxxxx.png and xxxxx@2x.png. And then put both two pics in your project. When your pic will be displayed in retina screen, system will automatically choose the one that is 640*1136 for you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, if you want to set a background image via UIView's backgroundColor, you will need to size down the image to 320 x 568 before you use it. This is because view.backgroundColor or [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] has no scaling property. Also, it would be good to scale down a background image to reduce the app size.

If you want to use an image of 640 x 1136, you will need to use UIImageView and specified its content mode. For example,

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Add the above line to your updated code and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried setting the contentMode as you suggest but for some reason it still stays the same enormous size.  I will try to reduce my image to 320 x 568 and see if that resolves it. THanks

Comment: I just noticed something. You initialized a viewFrame but did not apply it to the background imageView. That's why your image is still enlarged. Add this: `backgroundView.frame = viewFrame;`

Answer (score -1):

When you call `[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]` iOS assumes you have two images, one called BG.png which would be roughly 320x586 and a second image called BG@2x.png which would be 640x1136. You should create both images.

Alternatively you can use a UIImageView and set a scale mode. Then add that UIImageView to your window.

Comment: I tried creating two images and I still have issue.  I have also tried creating a UIImageView and sending it to the back.

Comment: If you use a UIImageView you must set the content mode to something like UIViewContentModeScaleToFill. You also need to set the frame of the UIImageView to the bounds of your existing view.