# Background image too large in window/view - Part 2

Tags: objective-c

This code here by sangony work for me really well but only on iPhone

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);


UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"];

UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[background CGImage]
                                           scale:(background.scale * 2.0)
                                     orientation:(background.imageOrientation)];

UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

[[self window] addSubview:backgroundView];
[[self window] sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Now how can I do the same idea, targeting both iPhones and iPads?

Original post can be found [Here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538214/background-image-too-large-in-window-view/17550151#17550151)

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not a UI expert, one thing which is peculiar is:

```
CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
```

Why is the size of `viewFrame` hard coded? Shouldn't it depend on the screen you are targeting? It should be proportional to the screen size.

And also, the background image should be a different size than the size of screen, and resolution is different on iPad and iPhone.

For this, either you can use the size of the screen to pick the appropriate image, as per the screen-size, or you can scale the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
```

I'm pretty sure you can get rid of this line of code completely:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
```

Now change `viewFrame` to `self.window.frame`.

In your example, you hard-coded the frame, so no matter what the device, it will always be that size.

Comment: thanks @the Tin Man, i was trying to do that but failed! really appreciate it, first time poster, long time reader

Answer (score 0):

Get the bounds of the window and set the frame

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:scaledImage] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
```